# Javascript scope issue inside a module

Tags: javascript

When declared like in the code below, `$sessionTimeLeft` is undefined when being accessed inside `updateSession()`. But when I moved `$sessionTimeLeft` declaration and assignment inside `initiate()`, I get the correct jQuery object. I think I can access `$sessionTimeLeft` when it is declared inside `initiate()` because of closure. But why is `$sessionTimeLeft` out of scope on my original code?

```
var session = (function SessionManager() {
  var timeLeftInMs;
  var timeLeftInMin;
  var delay; // in ms
  var $sessionTimeLeft = $('#dcSessionTimeLeft');

  /* Set up the module by setting the timeout and delay time. */
  function initiate(_timeout, _delay) {
    timeLeftInMin = _timeout;
    timeLeftInMs = timeLeftInMin * 60 * 1000;    
    delay = _delay; // delay in ms      

    setInterval(updateSession, delay);
  }

  function updateSession() {
    timeLeftInMs -= delay;
    timeLeftInMin = timeLeftInMs / 60000; // convert ms to min.              

    $sessionTimeLeft.text(timeLeftInMin);
  }

  var publicAPI = {
    initiate: initiate
  };

  return publicAPI;
})();

session.initiate(30,1000);
```

Comment: `session.initiate(30, 1000)`

Comment: Is `#dcSessionTimeLeft` loaded when you assign it to `$sessionTimeLeft `?

Comment: Please provide code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Its an excellent question if it's true. I don't know why people are down marking it

Comment: @TejaswiSharma it could be quite interesting. But it also could be down to the fact that the element with id `dcSessionTimeLeft` doesn't exist when the module is created

Comment: Yea, but I guess there is a typo in the code itself. Look my answer below.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek you are right. I called the js file inside a `ScriptManager` control that is declared right after the `<body>` tag and the function is self-invoked hence `#dcSessionTimeLeft` is not available yet. Please add your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `#dcSessionTimeLeft` is likely not yet loaded when you try to access it. So one way to ensure it is loaded is to wrap your code in a [`document.ready`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/):

```
$(function() {
  var session = (function SessionManager() {
  var timeLeftInMs;
  var timeLeftInMin;
  var delay; // in ms
  var $sessionTimeLeft = $('#dcSessionTimeLeft');

  /* Set up the module by setting the timeout and delay time. */
  function initiate(_timeout, _delay) {
    timeLeftInMin = _timeout;
    timeLeftInMs = timeLeftInMin * 60 * 1000;    
    delay = _delay; // delay in ms      

    setInterval(updateSession, delay);
  }

  function updateSession() {
    timeLeftInMs -= delay;
    timeLeftInMin = timeLeftInMs / 60000; // convert ms to min.              

    $sessionTimeLeft.text(timeLeftInMin);
  }

  var publicAPI = {
    initiate: initiate
  };

  return publicAPI;
  })();

  session.initiate(30,1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The closure should work absolutely well in this case too. The reason this code is not working because you have not called the session function correctly. Remember this function is returning a object with a function initiate

Last line of the code should be

```
session.initiate(30,1000);
```

This should work. To reproduce the issue I used node. I changed the $sessionTimeLeft variable to a string hello and tested if its still accessible in updateSession function. My code is

```
var session = (function SessionManager() {
  var timeLeftInMs;
  var timeLeftInMin;
  var delay; // in ms
  var $sessionTimeLeft = "Hello";

  /* Set up the module by setting the timeout and delay time. */
  function initiate(_timeout, _delay) {
    timeLeftInMin = _timeout;
    timeLeftInMs = timeLeftInMin * 60 * 1000;
    delay = _delay; // delay in ms

    setInterval(updateSession, delay);
  }

  function updateSession() {
    timeLeftInMs -= delay;
    timeLeftInMin = timeLeftInMs / 60000; // convert ms to min.

    console.log($sessionTimeLeft);
  }

  var publicAPI = {
    initiate: initiate
  };

  return publicAPI;
})();

session.initiate(30,1000);
```

And the result I got is

```
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
```

each every 1 second.